# Django two models share a table, run the unit test, then syncdb will report exception:table already exists

Tags: python, mysql, django, unit-testing

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "some_table"

class B(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column="name")
    class Meta:
        db_table = "some_table"
```

we get two models sharing a table, and we create the database schema manually via a customized command named `./manage.py db`.
but for unit test, when running `./manage.py test`, 
an error occurs: `"Table 'some_table' already exists"`.

how to avoid running `./manage.py syncdb` and execute the manual command?

Comment: not sure there's enough here. have you looked at the mock module

Comment: Try [`Meta.managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#managed)

Comment: But... why would you have two models sharing a table?